# Smooth transition between values (ease in/out)

Tags: c#, transition, smoothing, easing, quadratic

I'll probably get negative reputation for asking this question but I'm stuck and need help.
I need to do a nice and smooth easing between two values, the result being displayed in a textbox. For example, my textbox is showing "125" and have to grow smoothly to "25000" in 2.5 seconds with a nice quadratic acceleration and deceleration curve. I'm not good at C# and I'm used to "hack" pieces of code I can find on the web and build them together to do what I need but, for this, I can't find anything I've been able to use so far.
Is there anyone who can be kind enough to give me instructions, links or, even better a working piece of code to do this?
Thank you very much
 Vince.

Comment: "even better a working piece of code to do this" please post a non-working version and we can try to help you to fix it. ah and don't forget to describe where exactly you got stuck, error messages etc...

Comment: It'd help if you told us which UI framework you're using, is it WPF? Winforms? Something else?  I'm pretty sure there'll be "tweening" NuGet packages for whatever UI framework you're using

Comment: I simply vote to close as off-topic, because questions about tutorials and documentational stuff are off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: Piece of not working code: well... I even do not have such a non working code. When I search the web on how to do a smooth quadratic transition between values I do not get things I can try or use. Most of the answers are for Unity using Lerp functions that does not work in VisualStudio.

Comment: As for the UI, I'm using basic Winform. Thanks

Comment: @MadeByVince If my answer helped you please accept it, it's not nice to leave future visitors hanging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that the simplest way to do this is with quadratic formulas (as you have already figured out). There are online calculators that can give you a parabolic equation using three points, and when taking (0, 125), (2.5, 25000), and (5, 125) we get an equation of `y = -3980x^2 + 19900x + 125`. Translated into C#, this gives us:

```
var foo = -3980 * Math.Power(bar, 2) + 19900 * bar + 125;
```

After that, we can use a `for` loop and a small `sleep` time to transition smoothly from `bar = 0` to `bar = 2.5`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. I'll look at this and see if I can make it work (mainly because the example values I gave were just example and will be different every single time so I need to figure out how to calculate the equation on the fly). ;)

Comment: @MadeByVince in that case, generate a bunch of parabolas that intersect the x-axis at 0 and 5, then see what base equation you can multiply your value by to get the equation you need.

Comment: @MadeByVince Also, it just occurred to me that an "ease in, ease out" function might work better with a sinusoidal wave instead of a quadratic equation, as that will level out at both ends of the area.